# Mongodb Conversion to utf8

Tags: mongodb

In Java I. Am having below for conversion to utf8
byte titleValue[] = myString.getBytes(ISO_8859_1);

String value = new String(titleValue, UTF_8);

What we use for mongodb for above query...I searched a lot but found nothing

Answer (score 0):

By default, the MongoDB stores the String as UTF-8 encoded. So, no need to mention specifically while inserting the String data into MongoDB.

> BSON strings are UTF-8. In general, drivers for each programming
>   language convert from the language’s string format to UTF-8 when
>   serializing and deserializing BSON. This makes it possible to store
>   most international characters in BSON strings with ease. [1] In
>   addition, MongoDB $regex queries support UTF-8 in the regex string.